# Spreadsheet match row number and use in dynamic function

Tags: google-sheets, syntax, google-sheets-formula

I'm using a Google spreadsheet (although I can't get to work in Excel either) that has a list of dates in Column A including dates (sorted in order) in the past and future. I want to use a COUNTA function for all the rows up to today's date.

I can return the row position of today's date using;

```
=MATCH(today(),A:A,0)
```

Lets say this returns the number `15` as in Row 15.

However what I then need to do is reference this dynamically in my COUNTA function, e.g.:

```
=COUNTA(C3:"D" &(MATCH(today(),A:A,0)))
```

to replicate `=COUNTA(C3:D15)`.

This doesn't seem to work with the above syntax. I wondered if I need to use an INDIRECT function but I had quite a few tries and wasn't able to get the syntax right on that either.

Comment: Actually I've just fixed it now...

I was right it needed an INDIRECT function. I just had to keep playing with syntax.

    =CountA(INDIRECT("C3:D" & (MATCH(today(),$A:$A,0))))

Answer (score 1):

It seems your choice of INDIRECT was suitable, only a matter of getting the syntax right:

```
=COUNTA(indirect("C3:D"&MATCH(today(),A:A,0)))
```

[INDIRECT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377) returns a cell reference specified by a string - which in this case is the constant `C3:D` prepended to the result of your formula that calculates a row number.